# webview handshake failed

Tags: android, android-webview

I cannot call post request (Https) using webview. In my logcat I find this

> [1031/175452:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(905)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107****

It's not working in android 4.3

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show any code. What did you tried?

Answer (score 9):

**Quick Fix: Ignore SSL certificate error.**

```
    WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webView_about_alc);


    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(AboutAlcActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }

    });

    webview.loadUrl(ALC_ABOUT_PAGE);
```

-

**Better Solution:**
Fix the Android Network Security Configuration for your project. Follow the below link on how to do so.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: I tryed the better solution but couldn't make it work, so i used the quick fix, it's enought to me.